# TitleTextView not defined

Tags: android, textview

I'm working on a Lab for my class and can't figure out what is wrong with this xml. I keep getting an error.

[image]

If I hover over the xml it tells me The id `titleTextView` is not defined anywhere.

Here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:="@id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I first did it I had it misspelled and thought that it may have saved it somewhere I wasn't aware of. I've tried cleaning the project and deleting the xml file. I'm using it in a class here.

[image: PhotoPageFragment.java]

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error points you at Line 14.

Where you have `android:="@id/titleTextView"`

Compared to the correct line `android:id="@id/titleTextView"` or `android:id="@+id/titleTextView"`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you sir.

Comment: Welcome. The error outputs are surprisingly verbose if you know what to look for in the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating an id, it needs to have a `+`:

```
@+id/titleTextView
```

Comment: same with the `progressBar`

Comment: Actually, `android:id=`... instead of `android:=`

Comment: The android:id works. Should I really change the @id with @+id? The way I have it is how they show it in the Big Nerd Ranch book.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line
  android:="@id/titleTextView"
  to
  android:id="@+id/titleTextView"